# Debian Jessie Nginx 1.8.0 Symfony 3 returning 500 response

Tags: nginx, debian, symfony, php-7

I have set up a Symphony 3 site on my local computer that works. I then uploaded it to my server which is a Debian Jessie server with Nginx 1.8 set up on it with PHP 7 .

When i try and access the site i get the following error

> api.server.com is currently unable to handle this request. 
>   HTTP ERROR 500

When i look at the error logs i get the following:

```
2016/06/26 20:45:03 [error] 28099#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP 

message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught UnexpectedValueException: The stream or file "/var/www/aqua_note/var/logs/prod.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/aqua_note/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:97
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/aqua_note/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler->write(Array)
#1 /var/www/aqua_note/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/FingersCrossedHandler.php(112): Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)
#2 /var/www/aqua_note/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(336): Monolog\Handler\FingersCrossedHandler->handle(Array)
#3 /var/www/aqua_note/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(643): Monolog\Logger->addRecord(500, 'Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#4 /var/www/aqua_note/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/HttpKernel/EventListener/ExceptionListener.php(89): Monolog\Logger->critical('Uncaught PHP Ex...', Array)
#5" while reading response header from upstream, client: 108.46.158.41, server: api.servername.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "api.servername.com"
```

my nginx server configuration

```
server {
    server_name api.servername.com;
    root /var/www/aqua_note/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }

    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
      #return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

Can anyone please offer some help as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to setup permissions correctly:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#checking-symfony-application-configuration-and-setup

Do something like this:

```
$ HTTPDUSER=`ps axo user,comm | grep -E '[a]pache|[h]ttpd|[_]www|[w]ww-data|[n]ginx' | grep -v root | head -1 | cut -d\  -f1`
$ sudo setfacl -R -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
$ sudo setfacl -dR -m u:"$HTTPDUSER":rwX -m u:`whoami`:rwX var
```

From the Symfony3 install directory. The httpd user needs permission to the var directory. The user might be 'nginx' in your case, I'm not certain.

Comment: how to i know which user? is it www-data this is the user that has permissions to the /var/www folder

Comment: The first command determines that and stores it in the variable HTTPDUSER, so try running the above commands and see what happens.

Comment: I did a quick search online and the user should be stored in the `nginx.conf` file in a line like this: `user nginx;` But it could be different.

Comment: thanks so much i was going crazy over what I was doing wrong

Comment: Good news! Glad to help out!

Comment: I have one last question. Since I did that I keep having get the sudo message and I have to put in my password everytime i use sudo. There is usually a time gap before I have to put in the password again. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Go to [Unix & Linux StackExchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and ask the same question and you'll get a good answer. I've been wondering myself on that one...